# Connecting two points in a graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to use HighStock JS for graphical representation of JSON data and I want to connect two points on a graph using another straight line.. like for example..mine is a stock market graph and I want to connect the daily "highs" or "lows" inside that graph with a straight line... Is it possible to do that with a Highstock JS graphs??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with HighStock JS. After you create the graph, you can use the renderer.path method to create a path. It follows the same form as the SVG path. Here is a short little snippet that would create a line from the absolute coordinates (300,50) to (400,50). See the renderer documentation for more details http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#renderer

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    },
    function(chart) { // on complete
        chart.renderer.path(['M', 300, 50, 'L', 400, 50])
             .attr({
                 'stroke-width': 2,
                 stroke: 'red'
             })
             .add();
        });
    });​
```